# Programmatically creating colors for Vaadin Chart series

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

In Vaadin 14.4.2, is it possible to create a Chart with multiple series in a way in which the color of the series is programmatically calculated? Specifically, I may have ~100 series, but they all are associated with a "number" (specifically a mass of a chemical element). Since I know what in my application the "number" (ie the mass) will range from 100 to 2000, I would like the color of the series to range from blue (at 100) to red (at 2000). This way, when a user looks at the graph, they intuitively know whether the series refers to a heavy chemical (red) or a light one (blue).

In order to accomplish this, I think I would need to have some way of programmatically setting the color of a series, but I do not think that's actually possible in Vaading 14.4.2, right?

Here's an example of such a chart:
[image]

Comment: The Java API for setting colors was reintroduced in Vaadin 17, made possible by taking a new version of Highcharts into use. Looking at the roadmap https://vaadin.com/roadmap, the "Vaadin Charts upgrade" is currently scheduled to be included in Vaadin 14.5, which should be released in Q1 of 2021.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color of the data series is defined by the custom properties `--vaadin-charts-color-0`, --`vaadin-charts-color-1`, ..., `--vaadin-charts-color-9`. You can programmatically define their values like follows

```
charts.getElement().getStyle().set("--vaadin-charts-color-1","#2dd7a4");
```

The second string parameter is the color value, it can be any format accepted in CSS.

*Update: This answer applies to Vaadin 14, which has Charts always in styled mode. Note: In Vaadin 23 you can select between styled mode (CSS) and setting colors via Java API.*